# How to edit, hide and protect a single sheet whilst also keeping other sheets hidden and protected

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking a look at this question, I can't seem to find a solution that fits my needs.

I have a spreadsheet that has many individual sheets (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3...sheetx).

Sheet1 must always be visible.

Sheets 3,4,5....x must be hidden and protected such that they cannot be unhidden without unprotecting the workbook.

Sheet 2 must be normally hidden and protected as above but with the option of editing it after entering a password. The process of hiding and unhiding this sheet must not allow the user to see or unhide sheets 3,4,5....x

i.e the user must be able to hide,unhide and edit sheet 2 by use of a password but without ever allowing the user to see sheets 3,4,5,x etc.

Thanks again for having a look at this.
Charlie

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.  Please update your question to show the code you've attempted so far, and explain specifically what has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try hiding sheet 2 (right click --> hide) and then password protecting the workbook.

But before that go to VBA and paste and run this:

```
Sub HideSheets
    Worksheets("sheet3namehere").Visible =xlVeryHidden
    Worksheets("sheet4namehere").Visible =xlVeryHidden
    Worksheets("sheet5namehere").Visible =xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Doing this will remove the Unhide option for the above sheets from the user interface.

To unhide the sheets you will have to repeat the above but change xlVeryHidden to True.

Lastly you can password protect your vba project:  Tools --> VBA Project Properties--> Protection. You can use a different password from the one that you have used for the workbook.

This way the needed sheets can be hidden without the Unhide option from the menu. While sheet2 can be still unhidden in the normal way if the user has the password to unprotect the workbook.